Power Attributed to God by Spinoza
In his book "Ethics", I know his definition of God, who he understands as "an absolute infinite entity, that is, a substance consisting of infinite attributes, each of which expresses eternal and infinite essence".
My confusion stems from wondering if this attribute of God or any other attribute of God is causing his belief regarding ultimate power.
Therefore, what is his reasoning for attributing ultimate power to God? and asserting that no other force or idea can challenge this power? Or is this assumption simply inherent in his worldview?

@tkruse No, I am trying to understand whether this is an assumption or if he has a reason for believing this based on his definition of God.

It's not Spinoza's assumption of his worldview but his pantheistic reasoning result via his famous substantive Deus sive Natura thesis...

@DoubleKnot and does that tie in with him considering God as absolutely infinite? Since him being a pantheist is debated.

Spinoza's view of God as absolutely infinite is integral to understanding why he is sometimes called a pantheist, though not without controversy as you rightly mentioned...

"ultimate power"? There is "power" (potentia) in Ethics I, Prop.XXXIV. The distinction Potentiality vs actuality is "standard" in ancient and early modern metaphysics. See Note II to Prop XXXIII: "Further, all the philosophers whom I have read admit that God's intellect is entirely actual, and not at all potential."

What Spinoza defines as God is the totality of the universe, every thing there is ("Deus sive Natura" = God, A.K.A. Nature). It naturally follows that nothing can challenge God, since nothing is outside of, or separate from, God. A person can't oppose God anymore than they can oppose the universe. At best they can oppose an incomplete idea of God they have, a character they created in their head like for example the God of the Bible, but in that case the word "God" in their mind has a very different signification from what Spinoza means by God.
But keep in mind that Spinoza's God is not a personal being: it doesn't want anything or has any will (because, to want something it would first have to lack that thing, which is impossible by definition). Therefore the notion of "power of God" is kind of inadequate in Spinoza's phylosophy (if by "power" we mean the ability to do what one wants, God wants nothing so the concept of his power does not make sense).
